# How to create hierarchy table structure in oracle database

Tags: oracle

Trying to create the hierarchy in these 2 tables and I want only two columns in a table,First is parent and Second is child.How can I create tree table structure in oracle database .

```
First Table name - Product
Parent - Product
Child - Diet Drinks,Fruit Soda,Cream Soda,Root Beer,Colas
Product->   
        Diet Drinks —>  Diet Cream
                        Diet Root Beer
        Fruit Soda— >   Diet Cola
                        Strawberry
                        Orange
        Cream Soda->    Grape
                        Diet Cream
                        Vanilla Cream
        Root Beer—>     Dark Cream
                        Birch Beer
                        Sasparilla
                        Diet Root Beer  
        Colas———>       Old Fashioned
                        Caffeine Free Cola
                        Diet Cola
                        Cola    

Second Table name - Market
Parent -Market
Child - East,West,South Central

Market—>East—>  NewYork
                Massachusetts
                Florida
        West—>  California
                Oregon
        South—> Texas
                Louisiana
                New Mexico
        Central—>Illinois
                  Ohio
```

Comment: look at CONNECT BY queries

Comment: Hierarchical data structures like this are usually created in a single table in Oracle. As @OldProgrammer suggested, look at using CONNECT BY.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need something like this ?

```sql
--1.1 Product table
create table Product (
    Parent varchar2(50 char)
,   child varchar2(50 char) not null
)
;
--1.2 inserting Product data
insert into Product (Parent, child)
select 'Product', 'Diet Drinks' from dual union all
select 'Product', 'Fruit Soda' from dual union all
select 'Product', 'Cream Soda' from dual union all
select 'Product', 'Root Beer' from dual union all
select 'Product', 'Colas' from dual union all
--
select 'Diet Drinks', 'Diet Cream' from dual union all
select 'Diet Drinks', 'Diet Root Beer' from dual union all
--
select 'Fruit Soda', 'Diet Cola' from dual union all
select 'Fruit Soda', 'Strawberry' from dual union all
select 'Fruit Soda', 'Orange' from dual union all
--
select 'Cream Soda', 'Grape' from dual union all
select 'Cream Soda', 'Diet Cream' from dual union all
select 'Cream Soda', 'Vanilla Cream' from dual union all
--
select 'Root Beer', 'Dark Cream' from dual union all
select 'Root Beer', 'Birch Beer' from dual union all
select 'Root Beer', 'Sasparilla' from dual union all
select 'Root Beer', 'Diet Root Beer' from dual union all
--
select 'Colas', 'Old Fashioned' from dual union all
select 'Colas', 'Caffeine Free Cola' from dual union all
select 'Colas', 'Diet Cola' from dual union all
select 'Colas', 'Cola' from dual
;
commit;

--2.1 Market table
create table Market (
    Parent varchar2(50 char)
,   child varchar2(50 char) not null
)
;
--2.2 Inserting Market data
insert into Market (Parent, child)
select 'Market', 'East' from dual union all
select 'Market', 'West' from dual union all
select 'Market', 'South' from dual union all
select 'Market', 'Central' from dual union all
--
select 'East', 'NewYork' from dual union all
select 'East', 'Massachusetts' from dual union all
select 'East', 'Florida' from dual union all
--
select 'West', 'California' from dual union all
select 'West', 'Oregon' from dual union all
--
select 'South', 'Texas' from dual union all
select 'South', 'Louisiana' from dual union all
select 'South', 'New Mexico' from dual union all
--
select 'Central', 'Illinois' from dual union all
select 'Central', 'Ohio' from dual
;
commit;

--Hierarchy queries against the two tables
select 
    rpad(' ', 2*(level - 1), ' ')||PARENT PARENT
,   rpad(' ', 2*(level - 1), ' ')||CHILD CHILD
from Product
start with parent = 'Product'
connect by parent = prior child
order siblings by Product.child
;
--
select 
    rpad(' ', 2*(level - 1), ' ')||PARENT PARENT
,   rpad(' ', 2*(level - 1), ' ')||CHILD CHILD
from Market
start with parent = 'Market'
connect by parent = prior child
order siblings by Market.child
;
```